# Limit of recursive sequence $ a_{n+1} = 1+a_n^2/2 $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I do not know how to solve this problem:

> Find the limit of the following sequence: $ a_1 = 1 $ and $ a_{n+1} = 1+a_n^2/2 $.

I have proved that the sequence is increasing but I can not find the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(a_n)$ is increasing, $\frac12a_n^2\geqslant\frac12$ for every $n\geqslant1$ hence $a_{n+1}\geqslant a_n+\frac12$ for every $n$ hence $a_n\geqslant$ $____$ for every $n\geqslant1$, in particular, $a_n\to$ $____$ when $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to prove it is increasing.

If it had a finite limit $L$, taking limits on both sides of the recurrence, we get that $$L=1+L^2/2.$$ But this equation doesn't have real solutions.

**In general**, if you have a linear recurrence with constant coefficients, this is a way to compute its limit. Or more generally, for a recurrence of the form $$F(a_n,a_{n+1},\ldots,a_{n+k})=0,$$ with $F$ continuous, if the sequence has a limit $L$ then you must have $$F(L,L,\ldots,L)=0.$$

Comment: Assuming the sequence has a limit.

Comment: It says: "If it had a finite limit ..."

Comment: Yep, this is the uninteresting part of the question, the one students too often stop at, without realizing that showing no finite L can be the limit of the sequence is not enough to solve the problem. Making them believe that it is in fact enough is probably the greatest disservice one can provide. Congratulations.

Comment: The most important tool when working with limits of recurrences with constant coefficients is the fact that the limit **must** be a solution of the equation you get by taking limits on the recurrence. This is in fact the only general tool you have because all other tricks depend on the specific recurrence you have. Not teaching it, is what is a disservice.  Don't be sore if you didn't see it. You should haunt me when my solutions are wrong. There are going to be chances for it, I am sure. But when it is correct, and shorter than yours, you are only making a ridiculous. So please ...

Comment: Actually your solution is misleading (to put it politely), since it begins by "You don't even need to prove it is increasing", which make readers think that the rest of the post answers the question. But it does not. // Right, since the mathematical point is settled and since you are behaving as obnoxiously as is possible, my plan is to leave your pretty insulting and pretty wrong comments-to-come with no answer. Sorry.

Comment: The rest **does** solve the problem. What are you talking about? Assume the limit exists. Then it should be a solution of that equation. The solutions of that equation are complex. The limit of a real sequence cannot be complex. Then there is no limit.

Comment: Have you considered that a sequence which does not have finite limit might also tend to infinity, or it might not? The fact that it is increasing tells you which category this falls into.. I think this it what @Did hoped you would realise. If you fill in the gaps in his answer it becomes even more clear cut and obvious what the limit is.

Comment: @user84751 Yes, of course I saw that. But this guy likes to haunt me. He is still sore for something that happened sometimes before. Of course if you want more detailed information about how the limit does not exist you need to study the specific sequence closer. Even if it is not infinity, if it oscillates somehow then you can still compute asymptotics. So, even computing it is infinity is not the end of the story. Still, the first thing it should be done with a constant coefficient recurrence is to take limits on both sides.

Comment: @RGB supposing, playing devil's advocate, anything on the extended real number line was allowed to be the "limit", would it then be enough to conclude there was no finite limit? I might guess the question would want to know the asymptotic behaviour of the sequence, even if I find there isn't a finite limit. If I compute that the sequence tends to infinity, that, for me, would be the end of the story in this question. I doubt there is any worry about the rate.

Comment: [Sometimes before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461062/a-question-on-generalization-of-the-concept-of-derivative). Who should feel sore?

Comment: @user84751 Notice infinity is not a value, it is a zeroth order asymptotic. It just happens that culturally we get happy computing it and it is not so hard to teach how to compute it. Just as you may want to ask for that precision you may ask for more too. Now, notice Did didn't begin by saying that. He just began trying to nitpick in something that was actually said in the answer. He is just sore. And then tried to say the answer is a disservice, when it is the only technique that is applicable in general. When you are going to nitpick you should try to do it where there is a problem.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to respond anymore, though there are many good books on real and functional analysis out there that may help clarify limits and differentiation.

Comment: The arrogant assumption that I don't know what you are saying, doesn't make my answer less correct. That will not change. As it is not going to change that whenever Did comes to nitpick when he is not right I will pound him with the words he deserves. I am here to teach and learn mathematics. For those that are here to play pride games I have, at best, disinterest. I have said already all the important things that I had to say about this problem. That is enough for me. The next readers will be able to see in my answer the important technique that was missing otherwise.

Comment: @ABC I didn't have time for much of a response earlier, sorry if it appeared that way. What I meant to say is that there is a difference between giving a straight answer according to one's own interpretation of a question and giving an answer that has some pedagogical consideration behind it. I found during my university experience that questions of this sort were designed to make me think more about the important features of the object of study than simply to give me practice in brute force computation.

Comment: @ABC I do not see any evidence of defense of pride, nor would I consider Did's concern for the OP 'not right'. Also, regarding your point on infinity, it is possible to define a total order on the extended real number line, after which statements such as "+infinity is greater than any real number" become sensible, but I'm sure you are aware of that.